# Obter o campo CPF do e-CNPJ utilizando o certificate-core do demoiselle

Tags: demoiselle, demoiselle-certificate

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando o demoiselle-certificate-core versao 2.0.0. Ao manipular um objeto tipo X509, consigo extrair todos os campos como mostrado na documentação pelos métodos:
 `CertificateManager cm = new  CertificateManager(x509)` e pelo `cm.load(Cert.class)`. 
  O tipo de certificado é e-CNPJ, e ao carregar os métodos de manipulação do tipo PJ, não foi disponibilizado o método para receber o CPF do responsável, mas não há a opção no core do mesmo. Aparentemente por tratar-se de um e-CNPJ não deveria manipular o campo CPF, porém, quando carrego-o no programa certInstaller, o mesmo mostra além dos campos RG, Nome do responsável, orgão emissor, data de nascimento, dentre outros, também o cpf do responsável pela empresa. 
  É possível obter essa informação através do demoiselle-certificate?